# Residual division vs subtraction in a resource-product regression analysis

Tags: regression, residuals

When there are 2 variables where one is a product and the other one a resource required to generate that product, one measure of efficiency would be to compare the real product value to one obtained by a prediction of a regression model that correctly encapsulates the relationship  between the two.

One approach is to see the residuals, usually the higher residual values the higher the efficiency would be.

But, there are different ways of combining the model predictions and actual values to generate this difference with the expected result.

Two of them are simply subtracting the predictions to the values, and the other one is dividing the values by the predictions.

Which one of the two is better in general? Why?